# Meaning and origin of the word आद्विक

Tags: shiva, name

I am trying to understand the meaning and origins of the word आद्विक.

Comment: Hello, can you explain how it is related to Hinduism?

Comment: I must confess, my interest is linguistic understanding than spiritual. But if it's appropriate to ask this here, I apologize and retract my question.

Comment: One of our moderators tried for Sanskrit stack exchange and it was closed due to less support...  Hope we will try in near future again...

Answer (score 1):

The word *Aadvik* [means](https://shabdkosh.raftaar.in/Meaning-of-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%95-in-English#gsc.tab=0) unique. It is derived from *advitiye*.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know it's sandhi. How does Advitiye transform to Aadvik?